# Increment Number Property in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, counter, amazon-dynamodb, updates

How do I increment a number in AWS Dynamodb?

The guide says when saving an item to simply resave it:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html

However I am trying to use a counter where many users may be updating at the same time.

Other documentation has told me to use and UpdateItem operation but I cannot find a good example to do so.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html

However, I cannot find a method to implement the expression. In the future I will be adding values to arrays and maps. Will this be the same? My code is in Obj C

Currently my code looks like:

```
AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput *updateItemInput = [AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput new];
        updateItemInput.tableName = @"TableName";
        updateItemInput.key = @{
                                UniqueItemKey:@"KeyValue"
                                };
        updateItemInput.updateExpression = @"SET counter = counter + :val";
        updateItemInput.expressionAttributeValues =@{
                                                     @":val":@1
                                                     };
```

Comment: Add action can help to increase the existing value.

Comment: I don't understand how to write the code. I cannot find an example in the documentation on how to implement it. [dynamoDBObjectMapper save:newObject] ObjectMapper only seems to call delete and save not update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the last bit of code that actually makes the update item request:

```
AWSDynamoDB *dynamoDB = [AWSDynamoDB defaultDynamoDB];

[[dynamoDB updateItem:updateItemInput]
continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
    }
    if (task.exception) {
        NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
    }
    if (task.result) {
        //Do something with result.
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Comment: Not quite but my problem now is properly configuring my updateItemInput.key which is a much smaller problem.

Comment: If your key is a string you might need to modify the code that sets the key to something like this: `updateInput.key = @{ @"UniqueItemKey" : @"KeyValue" };`

Comment: I keep getting this when I try to pass my expression. 2016-04-07 17:23:11.774 toPic![46115:2812154] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[__NSCFString JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x107b7c2c8'

Comment: Without adding an update expression, it goes to task.error when the updateInput.key = @{@"KeyValue":[UniqueItem new]} but crashes with @{@"UniqueItemKey:@"KeyValue""} or when updateItemInput.expressionAttributeValues or updateItemInput.updateExpression is added. Thank you for your help I am finding AWS quite frustrating.

Comment: According to the docs : "The primary key of the item to be updated. Each element consists of an attribute name and a value for that attribute.

For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For example, with a hash type primary key, you only need to provide the hash attribute. For a hash-and-range type primary key, you must provide both the hash attribute and the range attribute."

Comment: @MikeDinesco  By creating this and setting it to my property name and passing this through my key I am getting an error with some funny results.  I think I am closer to what I need but not quite there. AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *newValue=[AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new];
            newValue.S = @"PropertyName";

Comment: @MikeDinesco I asked another question if you still wouldn't mind helping. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488229/incrementing-number-property-in-aws-dynamodb-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB if you want to increment the value of the any propertie/field you can use the UpdateItemRequest with action option ADD. I used in android this method would update the existing value of the field. Let me share the code snippet. You can use any actions such like add,delete,put etc.

```
.....
AttributeValue viewcount = new AttributeValue().withS("100");
AttributeValueUpdate attributeValueUpdate = new AttributeValueUpdate().withAction(AttributeAction.ADD).withValue(viewcount);
updateItems.put(UploadVideoData.FIELD_VIEW_COUNT, attributeValueUpdate);

UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest().withTableName(UploadVideoData.TABLE_NAME)
                                .withKey(primaryKey).withAttributeUpdates(updateItems);

UpdateItemResult updateItemResult = amazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(updateItemRequest);
....
```

You can see the above code will add 100 count into the existing value of that field.

This code is for android but the technique would remain the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. However I looked into many of these methods with objective c and Obj C's equivalent of AttributeValueUpdate is being replaced by updateExpressions which I am still struggling with and posted a new question about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488229/incrementing-number-property-in-aws-dynamodb-objective-c