# Incrementing Number Property in AWS DynamoDB Objective C

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, updates, increment

I am struggling with incrementing a number property value of an item already saved in my table on DynamoDB my code currently is:

```
        AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput *updateItemInput = [AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput new];
        updateItemInput.tableName = @"Table";

        updateItemInput.key= @{
                               @"KeyPropertyName":@"KeyValue"
                                };
        updateItemInput.updateExpression = @"SET(counter = counter + :val)";
        updateItemInput.expressionAttributeValues =@{
                                                     @":val":@1
                                                     };
        AWSDynamoDB *dynamoDB = [AWSDynamoDB defaultDynamoDB];

        [[dynamoDB updateItem:updateItemInput]
         continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
             if (task.error) {
                 NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
             }
             if (task.exception) {
                 NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
             }
             if (task.result) {
                 //Do something with result.
             }
             return nil;
         }];
```

My app always crashes when I do not comment out the updateExpression and expressionAttributeValues. I can reach the block when I create an empty instance of my item type and get strange results when I create an instance of AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue to pass in the key. Any suggestions? Am I also improperly writing my updateExpression?

I am also going to be adding updating and deleting items in array/list and dictionary/map properties on another object. How would this differ?

Comment: how does it crash? what is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: and yes, the update expression should be without paranthesis, and you may have to parameterize the attribute name as well

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[__NSCFNumber JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x113d10368'

Comment: updateItemInput.key= @{
                                   @"KeyPropertyName":[AWSItem new]
                                    };    This returns the completion block task.result but does not update the object

Comment: @MikeDinescu It keeps crashes with that error whenever the expression attribute values is not commented out

Comment: something must be wrong with how I am formatting my expressionAttributeValues, updateExpression, and/or if I include expressionAttributeNames

Comment: It looks like @YosukeMatsuda's answer pretty much covers what was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things. `key` is defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary<NSString *, AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *> * _Nullable key;
```

You need to replace `@"KeyValue"` with an instance of `AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue`.

`expressionAttributeValues` is defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary<NSString *, AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *> * _Nullable expressionAttributeValues;
```

You need to replace `@1` with an instance of `AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue`.

Make sure to use the latest version of the AWS SDK for iOS so that you can see the generics annotations in the header file. It helps you construct the proper request object.

Comment: Thank you @YosukeMatsuda . How would I create this instance of an AWSDynamoAttributeValue for @1? Is this the same if I am adding a value to a list or map as well?

Comment: Currently I have it as: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *keyValue = [AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new];
            keyValue.N = @"1";   updateItemInput.updateExpression = @"add counter + :val)";
            updateItemInput.expressionAttributeNames =@{
                                                         @":val":keyValue
                                                         }; But this keeps returning an error.

Comment: How did you get it to work? I am also having the same crash. Can you post your code, please?