# DynamoDB Update Item

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, updates

Could someone please give some basic code on how to update items? I am using it an have an app that needs to add/delete values to list and map properties on table items without completely deleting the value. I also have a number property that I need to use as counter. In AWS documentation it simply states to re-save the entire object. I know it is possible to update items in this manner however I cannot seem to find any code. My app is in objective c however this seems like a problem for many people using many languages so this may be a great place to answer this for any and all languages. Thanks.

Comment: @BobKinney I saw a response of yours on a similar question and thought that you might be able to help clear up some confusion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488229/incrementing-number-property-in-aws-dynamodb-objective-c  More specifically this question states my current problem